# React Component not re-rendering with useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to get my Navbar from antd to re-render using react useContext, where by default 'isAuth' is 'false', and upon user log in, it will be set to 'true'. From my understanding, through useContext, when 'isAuth' is updated, my Navbar should update as well, but it doesn't. Is my understanding in useContext flawed?

Here are the sample codes:

App.js

```
function App() {

return (
<BrowserRouter>
    <UserContextProvider>
       <Navbar />
    <UserContextProvider>
</BrowserRouter>
  );
 }
```

Navbar.js

```
export default function Navbar(props) {
const userContext = useUserContext();
return(
    <Menu theme="dark" mode="horizontal">
    <Menu.Item key="1" style={{ float: "right" }}>
        {userContext ? (
          <Menu.Item
            key="2"
            onClick={() => nav("/account")}
          >
            Account
          </Menu.Item>
        ) : (
          <Menu.Item
            key="3"
            onClick={() => nav("/signup")}
          >
            Login/Signup
          </Menu.Item>
        )}
      </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  );
}
```

UserContext.js

```
const UserContext = createContext();
const UpdateUserContext = createContext();

export function useUserContext() {
  return useContext(UserContext);
}

export default function UserContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);


  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={isAuth}>
    {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: add a useEffect() for isAuth and setIsAuth useStates so it renders when it changes. like this on your component  useEffect(() => {},[isAuth, setIsAuth]);

Comment: You need to call `setIsAuth` somewhere to trigger a re-render of your context and its children. I don't see that anywhere inside your `UserContext.js`.

Comment: Hi @Eddwin, thank you for your suggestion, will give it a try, however most of the examples I browsed through does not have useEffect so I assumed that there's no need to put one in.

Comment: Hi @Siddhant, `setIsAuth` is called in my `login.js` to change the state from false to true, I didn't add it here because it was a little too cluttering

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. Set provider value prop as an object:

```
return (
<UserContext.Provider value={{isAuth}}>
{children}
</UserContext.Provider>
);
```

And get isAuth state destructuring your context:

```
  const {isAuth} = useUserContext();
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel, thank you for your suggestion. However, the problem still persist.. I notice that `Navbar.js` does not run again when `isAuth` value changes but I just couldn't find out why despite wrapping it in `<UserContextProvider>`